# store navigation panel status once click on toggler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing bootstrapped website having navigation panel on left side, there is toggler of navigation panel,

```
<div class="sidebar-toggler"> </div>
```

When click on toggler it hide navigation pane and one more click shows navigation again,

What i want, that when user click on toggler, it stores as cookie and remains in that state whenever user log in or navigate to different pages,

How can i do this using jquery?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend [html storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) you can store data locally ,Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB)..

```
localStorage.setItem("toggler", "open");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cookie using

```
document.cookie = "sideBar=true";
```

where sideBar is the key and true is the value

You can retrieve a cookie using

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

To search for the specific key, like in this example for sideBar key

```
x = x.substr(x.indexOf('sideBar'));
```

And finally to get the value for sideBar key

```
x = x.substr(x.indexOf("=")+1);
```

Now you can use variable x to control the visibility of the sidebar

Here is a jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/1uphe7yL/1/